# strange behavior from ruby caesar cipher implementation

Tags: ruby

I am getting unpredictable response from this code, if the phrase used has only one word the output is as predicted, also if the shift is 0 it pushes things straight through. But when there are spaces in the phrase the shifting seems unpredictable. If someone can see the pattern, or enlighten me on what the methods are doing behind the scenes.(using the new1 array as the receiver yeilded an unaltered array)

```
def caesar (phrase, shift)
    alpha=('a'..'z').to_a
    #new1=[]
    temp=phrase.downcase.split('') 
    temp.each{|x| (temp[temp.index(x)]=alpha[(alpha.index(x)+shift)%26]) if alpha.include?(x)}

    p temp.join

end


caesar("abcde fghijklmnopqrs tu,,..vwxyz", 1)   
caesar("Frank", 1)  
caesar("Frank is a willy munching wombat.", 1)
```

results:

"abcde fghijklmnopqrs tu,,..vwxyz"

"gsbol"

"hucpo js b xjnlz mvodjing xombbt."

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere, to be honest I didn't even know what to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong as soon as a letter repeats itself:

```
temp[temp.index(x)]=...
```

Use each_with_index instead!

Comment: aha, so it is finding the first instance of 'x' instead of using the current instance, that makes sense. You are a gentleman sir.(not to be sexist)